# Creating polygon from one line

Tags: polygon, leaflet, line

I have found several solutions for crazy polygon detecting algorithms, however, my problem is a bit simpler.
I have a line created by an array of indexed points. Each click on map creates a new point and appends it to the end of the array, and creates a new line from the previous end to the new one.

I would like to detect when you create a point in a way that the line folds on itself and creates a polygon. I currently create a polygon when you click the first point again. Then all the points inside get selected.

[image: Detect this and select all points inside]

Here the 4th point was created and the line closed creating a triangle. Is there a simple solution to detect this?

Edit: Using leaflet library

Comment: What software are you using? Make sure to include that in your question.

Comment: Question was tagged, but I added it to the Q itself, thanks.

Comment: I've never used it, so I'm not sure whether it's entirely suitable here - but it sounds like the type of problem that Turf.js was designed to solve. See http://turfjs.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a modified version of an algorithm I found online.
It takes line A-B, C-D and returns their intersection, if there is any that lies on both input lines. So I iterated over my point array and then if any of them created a line that intersected the last line, a polygon was created, as previously when clicked the first point.

Said algorithm

```
function getLineIntersection(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy) {
    var d, a, b, n1, n2, result = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
    };
    d = ((dy - cy) * (bx - ax)) - ((dx - cx) * (by - ay));
    if (d != 0) {
        a = ay - cy;
        b = ax - cx;
        n1 = ((dx - cx) * a) - ((dy - cy) * b);
        n2 = ((bx - ax) * a) - ((by - ay) * b);
        a = n1 / d;
        b = n2 / d;
        if (a > 0 && a < 1 && b > 0 && b < 1) {
            result.x = ax + (a * (bx - ax));
            result.y = ay + (a * (by - ay));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```